# seagate ST3000DM001 spins and stops after 3 seconds

Tags: hard-drive, spinup

I have a Seagate Barracuda 3000GB.  When I connect it to motherboard using any version of Windows (7,8,8.1,10) when I connect the power supply cable it starts spinning makes 3 ticking noise and stops after 3 or so seconds and obviously OS will not recognise it.

I downloaded the Seagate for Windows tools to see if it can read it when its not spinning , no luck

I have the same model (working) with same PCB ( part of a NAS RAID drive) I changed the PCBs to see if the problem is from PCB but same result - spins down after 3 sec.  The only thing I haven't done yet is to change the faulty drive's BIOS chip and put it in the working PCB to see if that does any changes

faulty drives full info :
SN : W1F59FB5
MODEL : ST3000DM001
PN: 1CH166-515
FW: CC47
DATE: 14441
SITE: WU

Comment: Sounds like an internal hardware issue (example:spindle motor drawing too much current), you may have to send it to a professional if you have data you need.

Comment: to me it looks like a spin down timing issue , I had the same problem slightly deferent  with  Toshiba hard drive , but that was up for 5 min so I did connect to it using PUTTY to change the spin down settings

Comment: I'm hoping there is no need for opening the drive , that's a load of work 
I need a clone of the drive to replicate the raid and make the data

Comment: Try a usb adapter on the drive.